# Oracle 12c EF6. Compare DateTime stored as TimeStamp

Tags: c#, oracle, linq, entity-framework-6

I have column ModificationDate stored in  database as TimeStamp.
I'am using Oracle 12c database.

When i want to compare this date with other it looks like it lost precision during comparison, or somethink else happens....

Date value in database is '15/12/07 15:37:26,562000000'. And i'am using this queries:

```
            DateTime date = new DateTime(2015, 12, 07, 15, 37, 26, 562);
            var p1 = from p in entities.People
                     where p.ModificationDate > date
                     select p;
            Console.WriteLine(p1.Count()); //Prints: 1
            //Where condition: "Extent1"."MODIFICATIONDATE" > :p__linq__0

            var p2 = from p in entities.People
                     where p.ModificationDate > new DateTime(2015, 12, 07, 15, 37, 26, 562)
                     select p;
            Console.WriteLine(p2.Count()); //Prints: 0
            //Where condition: "Extent1"."MODIFICATIONDATE" > TO_TIMESTAMP('2015-12-07 15:37:26.562', 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS.FF')
```

Why when i'am putting datetime as variable i'am getting incorrect result?
Is there any possibility to make it work correctly with datetime variable?

Edit:
After few tries i found much easier example:

```
            DateTime date = new DateTime(2015, 12, 07, 15, 37, 26, 562);
            var p3 = from p in entities.PEOPLE
                     where date == new DateTime(2015, 12, 07, 15, 37, 26, 562)
                     select p;
            Console.WriteLine(p3.Count()); //Prints: 0
            //Where condition: (TO_TIMESTAMP('2015-12-07 15:37:26.562', 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS.FF') = :p__linq__0) AND (:p__linq__0 IS NOT NULL)
```

It looks like DateTime variable have different precision than timestamp. Is there is a possiblily to tell linq query to treat DateTime variable as TIMESTAMP ?

Comment: Could you give an example of the comparison, and explain what you expect (and post the results of the operation too)?

Comment: I think my code should be enough to understand my problem. You have 2 exacly same Linq queries that returns different results. It is probably problem of EF implementation for oracle. I think it treats DateTime parameter with less precission that database timestamp(6). I'am looking for solution how to make same query with Linq that will work correctly